# Symfony2 Doctrine Count ManyToMany Non-Related Records

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is the short story:

I have 3 tables (1 is just for manytomany relation), that's news and clubs.

News can be related to clubs with manytomany. It also can be no relational.

For example; i have news for 3 clubs. So, i have to choose clubs in my form.
Another example; i have news for general public. So, we would not choose any clubs.

So; i want to count non-related records with singleScalarResult.

Here is my query for getting results:

```
// Get entity manager
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

// Create query builder
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
->select('n')
->from('ATLClubBundle:News', 'n')
->where(
    $qb->expr()->isNull('n.deletedAt'),
    $qb->expr()->eq("n.newsType", ":type")
)
->setParameter("type", $newsType);

if (!$slug) {

    // if there is no slug choose both relational and non-relational news

} else if($slug == 'district') {

    // if slug is defined and slug is district get only non-relational news. This is working well with using having but if there any better way to do it, please let me know.
    $qb
        ->leftJoin("n.clubs", "c")
        ->andWhere(
             $qb->expr()->eq('n.showAll', 1)
        )
        ->having('COUNT(c.id) = 0')
        ->groupBy('n.id');
} else {
    // else, just get related news with clubs.
    $qb->innerJoin("n.clubs", "c");
}

    $qb
        ->setFirstResult($offset)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

This code block works well with getting results.

When i try to count results for paging;

```
$counter = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$counter
    ->select('COUNT(n.id)')
    ->from('ATLClubBundle:News', 'n')
    ->where(
        $counter->expr()->isNull('n.deletedAt')
    );

if(!$slug) {
    // same stuff as above
} else if($slug == 'district') {
    $counter
        ->leftJoin("n.clubs", "c", "WITH")
        ->andWhere(
            $counter->expr()->eq('n.showAll', 1)
        );
    // not working, throws exception with having or group by.
} else {
    $counter->innerJoin("n.clubs", "c");
}

$result = $counter->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

I receive an error (throws exception with having or group by)

Comment: so, basically, you're trying to add `having` and/or `group by` clause to your query??

Comment: Basically i want to count non-related records. I don't want to add any unnecessary codes.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is the error related to addition of having and/or group by?

Comment: Yes. When i try to use having  and / or groupby getting errors.

Comment: are the having / group by the same of first working snippet?

Comment: Yes it's same. But first one is working well without problems.